# changing URL permalinks in wordpress... the entire URL not just the extension

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I would like my short form or "truncated" posts on my home page www.justsaynews.com to redirect to entirely different website when a user clicks on a story.

possible?

Comment: I don't understand the question. What are the "truncated" posts?

Answer (score 0):

no. but you can use http://bit.ly 
there is a nice plugin.
just make sure you have the new url for each new post.

Comment: I know what bit.ly is but I am failing to see how to apply it in what you are saying.